# I accidentally uploaded the first version of my APK to the Google Play Store with a temporary self-signed certificate

Tags: android, certificate, apk, android-keystore

Without thinking, I compiled a version of my app using a "temporary self-signed certificate" (that's what Intell-J calls it anyway), and after testing locally I decided to upload that exact same APK to the Google play developer console for a proper beta test.

Now every time I try to upload a new version of my app I get the error:

> **Upload failed**
>
> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: *some SHA here* ]
>
> and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: *some SHA here* ]

Is there any way I start using the correct certificate/keystore file for signing my apps? Or am I pretty much scroogled?

Comment: Did you release to production or alpha/beta testing?

Comment: Only beta! Think there's still hope?

Comment: there is no way. You will have to change at least package ID of your application, and re-upload it as a completely new app.

Comment: Agree with everyone on being SOL, unless you opt-ed into Google Play App Signing https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en or review https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#release-mode and see if you can find the key that signed your build.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update an app by an apk signed with a different certificate. You need to register a new app and upload a properly signed apk there.

As a workaround to inform existing users about new app you may add this information to existing app and update it (still sign with previous certificate).